# How to call PetscFinalize from the root processor only?

Tags: petsc

In my Fortran program, I call an external function **only** at the **root processor**. I have a few checks to ensure that the function worked. If it doesn't work, then I `stop`the program and call `PetscFinalize`. For example:

```
if(rank==0) then
   call_status = external_function(x)

   ! function failed
   if (call_status/=1) then
      write(6,*) "external_function failed"
      call PetscFinalize(ierr)
      stop
   end if
end if
```

However, I noticed that during runtime, if there is an error with `external_function`, the program hangs and is not finalized properly.

My question is: what is the appropriate way to terminate the program at the root processor?

Answer (score 0):

call exit. 
PetscFinalize(ierr) is not designed for the stop of a program.